# compare row values between columns

Tags: python

I am new to coding and stackoverflow but I have been working on this problem all day and I cant seem to figure it out.

I basically have a df that contains the starting points and endpoints of a pass (this is soccer data) I have figured how to plot in a field the passes location and even the direction creating an arrow with the mplsoccer library. Now I just want to plot the forward passes. For this, I have thought to create a new df in which I only include the values in the rows in which the x value (the starting point of the pass) is < than the end_x (the end point of the pass since we attack left to right and the x coordinates start with 0 in the left and go all the way to 120 all the way in the right. This is the code I have but it does not work, I think it is a pretty simple way to do it.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.